# Is there an easy way to check for Role grant access overlap in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm sure this isn't uncommon in some Orgs, but we have an issue with a large number of roles in Snowflake. Is there an easy way to analyze overlap with role access? I have a suspicion that we have some tech debt with duplicate roles which is making it hard to manage data protection.

I was going to run a cluster analysis on grants to tables, but my R is a little rusty. I figured before shaking off that rust, I would see if anyone has done anything similar to this work.

Comment: Have you looked at `GRANTS_TO_ROLES` and `GRANTS_TO_USERS` views in `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE`

Comment: @demircioglu yes I have, that's where I'm pulling the data from. I was curious if anyone has ever actually done such an analysis. We have 176 roles active for a single DB and ~80% of those only have SELECT privileges. However, scrubbing them against each other is very tedious, so looking for a method to identify similarities.